# python matplotlib tick numbers collapsed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am puzzled that the same code works for the first chart below but not for the second.  The code is:

```
def decorate_plot(self, title, ylabel="Exposure", xlabel="Time / Years", legend_loc="upper right"):
    self.ax.set_title(title)
    self.ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    self.ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    self.ax.legend(loc=legend_loc, shadow=True)
    self.ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
        matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

Please how can I get the y-axis numbers on second chart to display correctly?

Axes ticks work here
[image: Axes ticks work here]

But y-axis ticks collapse here
[image: But y-axis ticks collapse here]

The numeric data for the charts initially was string format and so I used list(Map(float, ...)) to convert to float.  As this worked for the first chart I was puzzled that the next chart y-axis ticks collapsed.  On checking the Locals window I think the culprit is "seq" which show the y-axis numeric data as string again.  The processing is in C++ and python is used for displaying results.  Source code is at https://github.com/opensourcerisk/engine/releases
The two charts are in Examples_1 & _2 directories and the plot code is in ore_examples_helper.py in Examples directory.

Clearly odd that I can get the code to work for the first chart but not the second.  I managed to adjust the y-data as chart 2 plots ok.

The charts seem to be set up in this code but I cant see where data type gets specified.  Shouldnt Matplotlib automatically assume that numeric data for plots would not be in string format but in a numeric format?

```
    def setup_plot(self, filename):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.4))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot_name = "mpl_" + filename
```

Below is the Locals (my IDE is VS2017).  Ideally this data would be set to float on entering python but as I am not familiar with the code, is there a way to convert "seq" to float as a workaround please?

[Seq data is set to string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMm2W.png)

Comment: That sometimes happens  when you try to plot with non-numeric values. What kind of data are you using for your Y axis?

Comment: Is this a guess-my-input game? I suggest providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks.  The y-axis seq parameter has come in as a string for this chart but there is no such parameter for the first chart.  I have edited the question to show this.

Comment: @MrT The full model is public at github.com/opensourcerisk/engine/releases but I have had to tinker with the python to get it to cast numeric data not as strings. The input data comes from csv files generated by a C++ monte carlo. I'm surprised that Matplotlib would interpret numeric data as string type as I thought python was meant to deal with datatypes for the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the chart by casting the data input using list(map(float,...).

```
    def plot_npv(self, filename, colIdx, color, label, marker=''):
    data = list(map(float,self.get_output_data_from_column(filename, colIdx)))
    self.ax.plot(range(1, len(data) + 1),
                 data,
                 color=color,
                 label=label,
                 linewidth=2,
                 marker=marker)
```

I thought python and matplotlib would be more forgiving as to data type and am still trying to figure out why two the csv files ended up with the numeric data entering python as strings when running exactly the same code on the second chart.

Here is that chart as I think Quaternion intended:

[Chart with axes fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xwvp.png)